# Can I use area of effect targetting rules to Entangle a target 105 feet away from me?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

Entangle is a spell with a range of 90 feet. But, the wording of it...

> Grasping weeds and vines sprout from the ground in a 20-foot square starting from a point within range.

Can I orient the square so it points directly away from me, covering a 20x20 space which can encompass a creature which is 105 feet away from me?

Comment: I posted an answer and then realized I have no idea what the point of origin of a square is.

Comment: Someone should ask that as a question. Hey, looks like Thomas did. :-) https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177828/what-is-the-point-of-origin-for-a-square-area-of-effect/177836?noredirect=1#comment479170_177836 That question may make this question a duplicate.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker The rule I quoted at the very bottom of my answer here responds to an essential feature of this question that makes it not a duplicate. I think.

Answer (score 3):

#### It's up to the DM.

Notably, a square area of effect *is not defined in the Player's Handbook*. Most area of effect shapes are given clear and precise definitions for their points of origin. *We have nothing for the square*.

So we have two possible DM rulings.

#### 1. The point of origin is the center.

If the DM rules that the point of origin is the center of a square, then the furthest our *entangle* area can effect is 100 feet away. This ruling would be consistent with how spheres work.

This would bring *entangle* in line with the wording of the spell *grease*, which says:

> Slick grease covers the ground in a 10-foot square *centered on a point within range*

#### 2. The point origin can be any part of the square.

Since *entangle* lacks the "centered" language found in *grease*, it would be reasonable to rule that the point of origin can be any part of the square. If this is the case, then our *entangle* can affect area up to 110 feet away.

Either way, we know we can affect *some* area past the 90 foot range, because of the spellcasting rule that says:

> Once a spell is cast, its effects aren't limited by its range, unless the spell's description says otherwise.

Comment: Origin point aside, can you decide the orientation? Having it like a diamond would potentially allow the target to be caught up?

Comment: @SeriousBri Generally speaking, spells should be locked to the grid. If that creature can't stand half in one square and half in another, why can your spell work like that? There's no reason spells should get a special exception of not sticking to the grid.

Comment: @RevenantBacon If using a grid that's actually the rule - the point of origin must be an intersection of squares.

Answer (score 1):

### Maybe

The [spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting) rules tell us how to deal with cones, cubes, cylinders, lines and spheres but they don’t deal with squares. So, RAW, it’s up to your DM.

This particular DM would say use the rules for cubes as that seems to be the closest analog. Which means: yes, you can.

Answer (score -1):

I think that by it's terms ("square starting from a point within range"), it's up to 110'. Any point within 90' is "within range" and a square by its very nature 'starts' on the perimeter. Any point within the four sides is inside the square, so can't be the start of the square.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).